# Data stream join with apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, aggregate

I have an apache camel application where I have two routes (route A and route B) feeding data into an aggregator, it then outputs am object (C) containing data from both objects.

The object from the aggretator MUST contain a single object from each route (i.e. A and B). It mustn't contain two object from the same route (i.e. A and A)

My question is, how can I prevent from aggregating objects from the same route. I think I could do this by placing a restriction in the aggregator to join messages not only with the same correlation key, but also of different types.

I was wandering if this functionality already exists.

Many thanks for any advice.
    
    
    
    
    
       ${body}

```
<!-- messages from route B -->
<route id="routeB" />
<from uri="direct:startB"/>
<to uri="ldap:ldapcontext?base=DC=company,DC=net"/>
<split>
   <simple>${body}<simple>       
   <marshal ref="ObjectBJsonConverter"/>
   <unmarshal ref="ObjectBJsonConverter"/>
   <!-- add correlation key in header as 'objectid' -->
   <to uri="bean:myProcessor?method=addObjectBCorrelationKey"/>
   <to uri="seda:myAggregator"/>
</split>

<!-- aggregate the messages, create new ObjectC that contains ObjectA and ObjectB -->
<route id="aggretatorRoute">
<from uri="seda:myAggregator"/>
<aggregate ref="myEntityAggregator" completionSize="2" completionTimeout="200000" discartOnCompletionTimeout="true" ignoreInvalidCorrelationKeys="true">
  <correlationExpression><simple>${in.header.objectid}</simple></correlationExpression>
  <to uri="bean:myProcessor?method=doSomethingWithObjectC"/>
</aggregate>
```

Comment: You may need to check out the EIP implementation of the resequence, but I'm not sure if it can work out of box for you case.

Comment: Please post the sample code that you are using currently now . We can go ahead from there.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't have a solution for this problem, currently I just assume that the messages form routeA and routeB  won't contain objects with same type and same ID.